# How to choose an AES padding mode?

Tags: security, encryption, encryption-symmetric, block-cipher

Depending on the framework you are using, there are various padding modes that can be used with AES encryption. For example, with .NET we can choose PKCS7, ISO10126, ANSIX923, Zeros or None. Similar options are available in Java.

I understand that the encryptor and decryptor need to use the same mode to be interoperable.

What considerations are there when choosing a padding mode? With the exception of 'None', does it even matter which you choose? Can some be considered more secure than others?

Comment: See my answer on Crypto - Stack Exchange: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1486/how-to-choose-a-padding-mode-with-aes